# Probing system file interactions

Tags: filesystem, programming, monitoring

I need to monitor all interactions with Linux file system (include interactions through interrupts, kernel functions and system calls). To do this, I use `SystemTap`. I have two questions:

1. According to my goal, is virtual file system monitoring equivalent to file system monitoring?
2. What event(s) should I probe using `SystemTap`?

Comment: It looks like you want us to do your homework/breakin for you. No.

Comment: You're wrong. It's not my homework. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer a long time ago but forgot to share it here.
1.Yes. The VFS is an abstraction layer that gives applications access to different types of file systems and local and network storage devices. According to [here](http://www.linuxchix.org/content/courses/kernel_hacking/lesson6) both the generic filesystem code (VFS) and the code for each different filesystem are found in /fs directory.
2. So using `SystemTap` you can probe `kernel.function("*@fs/*.c").call` and `kernel.function("*@fs/*.c").return` for incoming interactions and `kernel.function("*@fs/*.c").inline` for outcomming interactions (if you ignore functions that there are in *.c itself).